# After updating Android Studio 2.3, it does not debug completely

Tags: android, android-studio

I have just updated my AS 2.2 to 2.3.
The problem is that now AS does not show me the error lines, if the app has an error, it shows:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

I googled, the most thing that an other program uses this port, but I do not think so:

Can anyone help me?

[image: show the ports here]

if I try to change my Gradle version from 3.3 to 2.3, I get this error:
[image: Image 2]

Comment: could you please share your gradle version you are using ?

Comment: i use Gradle version 3.3

Comment: But 3.3 is not released yet..max gradle version is 2.3.0 from where you are using 3.3 >

Comment: automaticly after updating on Android Studio 2.3
I did not do any change

Comment: change it to 2.3.0 and it will work as you are expecting

Comment: I did, but android studio needs minimum 3.3 !!!
error : minmum supported Gradle version 3.3

Comment: Put gradle version as : 2.14.1 and Android Plugin Version as : 2.2.3

Comment: i have tried with version 2.14.1 and Plugin 2.2.3  but i get this error :
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: C:\Users\PC1\AndroidStudioProjects\TestApp\app\build\tmp\expandedArchives\classes.jar_87ivalr21t6mit0vddmnfqm3c\com\google\android\gms

Comment: go and delete the tmp directory forcefully via command line

Comment: i have tested on other pc. now i get no error using Gradle version 2.14.1 and Plugin 2.2.3 but I get again the first message :    Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'

Comment: @dex The latest Android build tools require Gradle 3.3 or higher https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html The Android Build tools version is unrelated to Gradle version numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixes this Problem with new Insall  of Android Studio 2.2.3 (before SDK deinstalled too)
which has Gadle verion 2.1.14 and Plugin 2.2.3

I have opend my project again and ofcourse i must change the gradle version and plugin like from 3.3 to 2.1.14

I hope that will help other when they can  not find other way.

Answer (score 0):

> Connected to the target VM

The isn't an error. It connected...

> Minimum supported Gradle version is 3.3.

You are using Android Gradle plugin `2.3.0`, [so Gradle `3.3+` is required](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle).

If you must downgrade Gradle, you'll lose other features (like Instant Run, I think) and have slower build times, but you also need to downgrade the android plugin version.

Comment: I have updated again on 3.3. no errors but Android studio does not show me the errors by debugging when the app gets crash for example. before was OK

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but use `logcat` in the terminal to check your connection after you possibly restart your computer to clear away all the `studio64` processes